# How to set cursor to busy until document.ready is called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set the cursor to busy as soon as page load starts and want to change the cursor to normal when `$(document).ready` is called since I see it takes couple more seconds for this `$(document).ready` function to be called.

What is the way to do it?

All I could find is [here](http://www.codingforums.com/javascript-frameworks/193009-jquery-denote-cursor-busy-until-ready.html). Not sure if it's the right way to call.

Comment: The only I have with that link is that it uses jQuery to change the cursor style when using plain CSS in the head makes more sense to me.

Comment: try creating a masking div in your page body and give it a z-index higher than 1 with the cursor: wait css property on that div and in the document.ready event, just hide that div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

CSS,

```
* {cursor:wait}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $('*').css({cursor: 'auto'}); });
```

Comment: in case of JQuery not loaded or Javascript disabled it'd show as busy forever.

Comment: That is true, Okay you could leave the css alone and do this, $('*').css({cursor: 'wait'}); }); $(document).ready(function(){ $('*').css({cursor: 'auto'}); }); This will set the cursor to wait as soon as the js script is read but wont set it back to auto until the DOM is ready.